# What should I do about a horizontal crack around my porch slab?

Tags: concrete, foundation, crack

This crack runs all the way around my porch slab but doesn't go into the foundation where the basement starts. The ranch house was built in 1956. The porch was framed in and our office is in there now. I don't know if the crack was there when we bought the house but I assume it was. The porch sits next to a garage.

Is something I should be concerned about? If it's only cosmetic, what would be the best way to fill it in?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with Johnnyz that it seems harmless.  I would fill it with outdoor caulking.  I'm not sure what your climate is but if water gets in and freezes then you have a bigger crack.

Answer (score 0):

The crack does not look serious to me but it is a small picture. You will often get a crack where 2 concrete masses meet that were poured at different times. As long as the floors feel sound and flat I would just monitor the crack and see if it widens.